# how to read a txt file and store in NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, robots.txt

i am trying to read a txt file and store it in a NSArray. here is my code, but it seems there is something missing that i don't know!

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/robots.txt"];

    NSMutableArray *robots=[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSLog(@"%@",robots);
```

Comment: I think @anticyclope nailed this one, but in future, please say more about what's wrong -- just saying "something's missing" doesn't describe what you expect and what you're seeing and why they're different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to load the contents of URL into string first like

```
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Then split this string like this:

```
NSArray *parsed = [content componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Now `parsed` array will contain strings from the URL.

**Edit:**

If you want to filter your array, add this code:

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [parsed indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSRange range = [(NSString *)obj rangeOfString:@"Disallow"];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        return YES; 
    }
    return NO;
}];

NSArray *disallowed = [parsed objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

`disallowed` will be populated with the strings that contains `Disallow` string

Comment: thank you, that helped! how can i return only those lines that contain @"Disallow" string ?

Comment: what is the first line? is it a method? what are those parameters ?

Comment: This line returns indexes ob object, that are passed some test, substring matching in this case. It enumerates all objects in array and see if this object is passing the test. It uses blocks, an Objective-C feature, like anonymous function in some other language, to run the test over each enumerated item. It does return YES, if substring is matched, no otherwise. obj is an object from an array, idx is its index. Also, if you do want to stop the test, you may return YES in stop variable.

Comment: thank you so much, but i think it has A problem, it deos not work, could you plz check it out?

Comment: Blocks are introduced in iOS 4 / Mac OS X 10.6. Work for me in Mac OS X 10.7.